# Block the user from changing the System Date/Time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

We have a windows application (C# .net) and we'll be giving installers to client. The requirement is that once the application has been installed , user should not be able to edit the system time/date  . This is to make sure that the application generated dates/reports are not manipulated. 
My target OS is Win-XP
What is the best way to do that ?

Does OS provide any facility to do that ?

Client machine is a stand alone machine and is not on any network.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I believe this question would be better suited on Server Fault since the answer will most likely have to do with windows permissions.

Comment: Consider that in many parts of the world that observe Daylight Savings Time, the time will *need* to change twice a year in order to remain accurate, whether the user manipulates it or not. Your application will need to provide a facility to keep the current date/time updated if you disable this in the host OS.

Comment: In my opinion this requirement is actually a very serious design flaw in the application and you should seriously consider some of the solutions mentioned, like a central timestamp distribution mechanism using signing, etc. Imho an application should be able to enforce it's own policies and not be dependent on it's environment for enforcing those policies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said here already, you can use group policies, but they are easily circumvented. Also, your customers may react hostile (rightfully so) if your app does that. Still, in case your application is in a closed network, talk to the sysadmin and get it rolled out as a policy.

If you really need a trusted time source, then do so: Write a Web Service or use an existing NTP Service that your application contacts and use the time returned by that trusted service. Then use signing techniques to prevent tampering with the reports afterwards.

Downside: you need internet access. Possibility is to have the client setup a NTP Server within their network (AFAIK Windows Domain Controllers can do that automatically?) and use that, but then the client can again tamper with it.

But bottom line is: Contact a webservice to make tampering hard or use group policies to make tampering easy. Making tampering impossible isn't possible anyway.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But the machine is stand alone which is not connected to network. Is there any other way apart from Group Policy?

Comment: @Ananth I'm not aware of any. Group Policy also applies without a network, I think it's called Local Security Policy then. One other option: have your application remember the last time stamp and check on every report generation if current is smaller than last. That is also not tamper-proof (and make sure it does not cause problems in Daylight Savings time!), but it's an option.

Comment: Thanks .Your option will definitly serve the purpose

Answer (score 3):

That sounds more like a server-fault question; I wonder if "group policy" is the way to do that on a per-machine basis;

However - for a *programming* answer - why not get the time from a central server when your app starts? Calculate the offset from the *local* time and apply that throughout your app.

If security needs to be tight you may need to sign the response from the server to prevent spoofing (in particular via "hosts" etc).

Comment: Thanks Marc. We can do that only if we are sure that all client machines are connected to Internet

Comment: @Ananth I never said the server had to be internet based; it could be on the LAN

Comment: @Ananth re your "not connected to network" remark to Michael - ultimately, anything can be circumvented - take a pin to the CMOS battery, for example. Hack the BIOS and change it there. Boot from a USB pen and change there... swap the boot disk... so many options.

Answer (score 3):

You block this by changing Windows Policy. You can either do this from Active Directory (Group Policy) or by manipulating the local seurity policy.

See link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113557-date-time-allow-prevent-users-groups-changing.html

But I would rather recommend that you check time with an online server instead. Preventing such a thing for users may give them big problems if their BIOS resets or something.

Comment: Thanks Tedd. But the machine is stand alone which is not connected to network. Is there any other way apart from Group Policy?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible because that is related to group policy rather than your application changing any system settings which will prevent users from changing system date time. Go through these it might come of use -

1. If XP Pro, use the Group Policy Editor to create fine-grained
   permissions.Start>Run gpedit.msc [enter]
2. If XP Home, look at Doug Knox's Security Console and see if it will do
   the job for you: http://www.dougknox.com

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't prevent a basic OS function like this (aside from a group policy...but not programmatically, especially if the users had admin permissions).  *If* you could do this programmatically, it could easily be exploited for mis-use (changing the time and breaking Kerberos authentication for example).

Comment: Thanks Nick. But the machine is stand alone which is not connected to network. Is there any other way apart from Group Policy?

Comment: @Ananth - not that I'm aware of, but policies can be applied to standalone machines, provided the users don't have local Admin privileges to override them...is that the case?

Comment: i think it is..This is definitly something which I'll try to implement.But is it possible to edit the policies programatically ?ie when we install the application

Comment: @Ananth - if your program has permissions, sure...I'm not sure how much of that Win32 API is exposed through a C# wrapper (though *surely* someone's written one).  If you want quick/dirty, registry keys are a much faster/simpler, but not as future-safe if they change (though that's pretty unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Only through [Domain policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731654%28WS.10%29.aspx) - admins must prevent the user not to mess with the time.

Windows 2008 has an option to sync time with internet.

**Alternative is that you create a web service that your app could access through internet and get the non-modified time.**

Comment: Thanks Aliostad. We can do that only if we are sure that all client machines are connected to Internet

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement local or group policy for that. I don't know if you can easily manipulate it from C#.

Comment: Thanks fejesjoco. But the machine is stand alone which is not connected to network. Is there any other way apart from Group Policy?

Comment: Analogous to the domain group policy is the local policy. Start->run->gpedit.msc

Comment: Thanks..But can that be edited programatically. ie when we install the application

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these machines are not actually under your administrative control then clearly you can't do this.  But an alternative would be to get the time used to generate your timestamps from an external web service,  you could use some sort of encryption to access the service to ensure the client can't tamper with the result en-route.

Comment: Thanks James. We can do that only if we are sure that all client machines are connected to Internet